# Windows Firewall how to allow only Remote Desktop from ip range like 118.102.*?

Tags: windows, firewall, remote-desktop

I would like to limit remote desktop to my Windows Server 2008 by only allowing ip from a range starting with 118.102.*

If I set 118.102.0.0 - 118.102.0.255 then it seems like I need to add 118.102.0.0 - 118.102.1.255, 118.102.0.0 - 118.102.2.255 and so on...

118.102.0.0 - 118.102.255.255 doesn't seem right too.

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with 118.102.0.0/16 or 118.102.0.1 - 118.102.255.254